# Displaying geographical coordinates from a dxf file on a device context

Tags: python, wxpython, device, scaling, ezdxf

I'm trying to display rectangles from a dxf file on a device context using ezdxf and wxpython. But this is not displayed with correct scale and seems out of device area.

```
class draw(wx.Window):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Window.__init__(self, parent, -1, (-1, -1), (1000, 650))
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#888")
        self.CenterOnParent()
        self.pen = wx.Pen("#ff0000", 3, wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID)
        self.brush = wx.Brush("#ff0", wx.TRANSPARENT)
        self.posFrame = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "[0, 0]", (-1, -1), (-1, -1))
        self.textFont = wx.Font(10, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        self.posFrame.Show(False)
        self.pos = (0, 0)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, ev):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetMapMode(wx.MM_TEXT)
        dc.SetAxisOrientation(False, True)
        dc.SetDeviceOrigin(264800, 745800)
        # dc.CalcBoundingBox(270000, 750000)
        # dc.SetUserScale(0.008238, 0.005392)
        dc.CrossHair(500, 325)
        s1 = msp2.query("LWPOLYLINE").entities
        self.pen.SetWidth(1)
        self.pen.SetColour("#ff0")
        dc.SetPen(self.pen)
        dc.SetBrush(self.brush)
        for x in range(len(s1)):
            pts = []
            for y in range(len(s1[x])):
                coords = s1[x][y]
                coordX = coords[0]
                coordY = coords[1]
                coordZ = coords[2]
                coordXYZ = "({}, {}, {})".format(coordX, coordY, coordZ)
                # print(coordXYZ)
                pts.append((float(coordX), float(coordY)))
            dc.DrawPolygon(pts)
```